# How to create a raster heightmap from contour lines in a vector layer

Tags: qgis, interpolation

I'm a beginner with GIS software and I'm trying to get a raster greyscale heightmap from contour lines (read from a GeoPackage) in QGIS.

I'm using the Grid interpolation tools (menu Raster>Analysis>Grid (***)), and I'm faced with two issues:

1. It only seems to work from points vector layers and not lines (I'm not able to select a line layer in the dialog box).
2. If I use a point layer (for test purposes only), I cannot find how to specify the 'size' of pixels (which are way too big with the default settings).

Am I using the right tool? What am I missing?

Comment: To point 1: extract vertices of the lines to get points that you can use. You can also first densify the line to get more and regularily spaced vertices.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The easiest way would be to use TIN-Interpolation from the Toolbox which can take a contour-line layer for input:

[image]